# Phonegap 3.3 project creation through node

Tags: node.js, cordova, startup, phonegap-build

Hi im trying to start a project with phonegap 3.3. The problem I have is trying to get node to start the project. I have the environment variables set up and I have ant included in the set up.
This is the error I get(If more information is need I will provide it)

```
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

C:\Users\denis\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\denis\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:8
7:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\denis\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_mod
ules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\denis\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js
:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\denis\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_
modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\denis\.cordova\lib\android\cord
ova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\denis\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js
:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\denis\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules
\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: did you do a cd to your app folder before you launch the add platform command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with environment variable path: Follow this.

Set Environment variables:

```
Path:
Start -> Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Environment variables 

Or

Mycomputer -> Right Click -> properties -> Advance System settings -> Environment variables

1. Java JDK
2. Android SDK
3. ANT
```

User variables for user1:
   Path: %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\

Temp:
   %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp

System variables:

ANDROID_HOME: C:\Nithi\software\Android_sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\
   Path:

ANT_HOME: C:\ant

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\

JAVA_PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin

Path: c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools